# JPA 2 delete childs exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a problem with JPA 2 (Hibernate) + MySQL. I want to remove root entity and child elements. This relation is Many to Many and contains additional fields in middle table.

When I execute delete invoking the method "entityManager.remove(entity)" an exception is throwing.

Some help please.

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_gestionproyectos`.`proyectos_recursos`, CONSTRAINT `FK_proyectos` FOREIGN KEY (`proyecto_id`) REFERENCES `proyectos` (`ID_proyecto`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
```

Proyecto.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "proyectos")
public class Proyecto implements BaseEntidad<Long> {
   ...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyecto", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ProyectoRecurso> recursos;
```

Recurso.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recursos")
public class Recurso implements BaseEntidad<Long> {
   ...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recurso", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ProyectoRecurso> proyectos;
```

ProyectoRecurso.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "proyectos_recursos")
public class ProyectoRecurso implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private ProyectoRecursoId id;

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name = "proyecto_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Proyecto proyecto;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "recurso_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Recurso recurso;

@Column
private Double disponibilidad;
```

ProyectoRecursoId.java

```
@Column(name = "proyecto_id")
private Long proyectoId;
@Column(name = "recurso_id")
private Long recursoId;
```

Logic code for remove entity of type Proyecto

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void eliminar(final Long id) {
   final Proyecto aux = getEntityManager().find(Proyecto.class, id);
   if (aux != null) {
      getEntityManager().remove(aux);
   }
}
```